# Laravel Call to a member function delete() on null

Tags: laravel, sql-delete

in PegawaiController i use join to take nama_departemen from Departemen table

```
public function index()
{
    $data_pegawai = Pegawai::join('departemens','pegawais.id_departemen','=','departemens.id')->paginate(5);
    return view ('pegawai.index', compact('data_pegawai'));
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    Pegawai::find($id)->delete();

    return redirect()->route('pegawai.index')->with(['success'=> 'Item Berhasil Dihapus']);
}
```

in pegawai.index

```
@forelse ($data_pegawai as $item)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-center">{{ $item->nomor_induk_pegawai }}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">{{ $item->nama_pegawai }}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">{{ $item->nama_departemen }}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">{{ $item->email }}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">{{ $item->telepon }}</td>
                                            @if($item->gender==0)
                                            <td>Wanita</td>
                                            @else
                                            <td>Pria</td>
                                            @endif
                                            
                                            @if($item->status==0)
                                            <td>Inactive</td>
                                            @else
                                            <td>Active</td>
                                            @endif

                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <form onsubmit="return confirm('Apakah Anda Yakin ?');" action="{{ route('pegawai.destroy', $item->id) }}" method="POST">
                                                    <a href="{{ route('pegawai.edit', $item->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">EDIT</a>
                                                    @csrf
                                                    @method('DELETE')
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Hapus</button>
                                                </form>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @empty
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        Data Pegawai belum tersedia
                                    </div>
                                    @endforelse
```

im trying to delete data with DELETE button. it said Call to a member function delete() on null but sometimes it work. i use the same code for delete button in departemen.index and it working fine. how to fix this?

Comment: Departemen::find($id) didn't return anything. Perhaps because your missing the  t

Comment: ***but sometimes it work.*** you need to debug your application line by line. Cz provided data looks okay, and nothing wrong

Comment: If below solution not works then can you please explain more and share more controller, route and index file details

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's working because the data is not deleted in that case it works. And when data is deleted and you are redirecting again that page then an error will throw as  Call to a member function delete() on null.

To ignore this value you have to simply create a list view. when you are redirecting to the list view which contains all data which are not deleted

Answer (score 0):

First, you need check if there is a record with that ID before trying delete it.

The best way to do it is typing the param.

In Controller:

```
public function destroy(Pegawai $pegawai)
{
    $pegawai->delete();

    return redirect()->route('pegawai.index')->with(['success'=> 'Item Berhasil Dihapus']);
}
```

In the route file you need change the param name from `$id` to `$pegawai`.

Laravel will check if the ID is valid before enter into the function.

Comment: in routes.web file im using 
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});

//Route Resource
Route::resource('/departemen',\App\Http\Controllers\DepartemenController::class);
Route::resource('/pegawai',\App\Http\Controllers\PegawaiController::class);
Route::resource('/proyek',\App\Http\Controllers\ProyekController::class);

Comment: @BruhBrah great. Your pegawai resource is well set up. It must work with the method I sent above.